# Find Microsoft Windows Installer 3.1 or later

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer

How to find using C# Microsoft Windows Installer 3.1 or later is installed in machine?Can anyone help me how to do this using C#.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check to see if this line returns a version number higher than "3.0.1" :

```
return System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\msi.dll").ProductVersion;
```

Comment: :Hai Hamido thanks for the reply and the code.I could able to get the value.